What is the difference between processing from TOM API and from XMLA?
When I do a "process full" in my table, in my Net Core API, only take 1 second, but when I do the "process full" through the Management Studio the process take more seconds. In the second case, the process is working well, but in the first case the process is never performed
In my Net core API
Tom.Table table = database.Model.Tables["MyTable"];
table.RequestRefresh(RefreshType.Full);
database.Model.SaveChanges();

And in Management Studio
{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "full",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "mydatabaseAbc",
        "table": "MyTable"
      }
    ]
  }
}

What is the difference between the two?
I have a database in Analysis Services Tabular and the table is with direct query. I'm trying to process the table because I have other problem (I create the table and then, when I query it, take a long time in the first query, but that is for other question here on Stack Overflow)

Unless you've made changes to the database, you shouldn't need to process the DiirectQuery data source. The main reason for Process Full is to refresh data in an Import mode table. See my comment on your other question about performance and DirectQuery.
